# App is available for my device, but I can't install it?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

My app is live on play store from today. But when try to install the app, the install button is white. That's why anoyone can not download the app.

How can I solve the problem? Please help me :(
[It is shown like the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itix2.jpg)

I am new here. I can not understand what should I do now. Please help me!

Comment: the error message is quite clear, your device cannot install the app, and the reason can be related to the android version, what is your app's minsdkversion?

Comment: check play store console, Release > Device catalog, you will which device is supported and  which is not